# When to use robust SE in weighted survival analysis?

Tags: r, survival, propensity-scores

When do you use robust standard errors in a weighted survival analysis?
Generally in a weighted analysis or are there other reasons for this?

The `survival` package description of `coxph` says the default of `robust =` is TRUE if …there are case weights that are not 0 or 1…

and what is the robust SE in that case?

Thank you

Comment: What’s the reason for weighting?

Comment: Why the interest in ATE?  It may not apply to any individual if there is outcome heterogeneity.  Weighting can greatly increase variance also.  Weighted methods are inefficient in general.

Comment: because the question is if a specific treatment should be applied to all patients.

Comment: @gisela it sounds like you have many preliminary problems to your current problem. Weighting is an inefficient method to handle the empty matching strata, and robust errors estimation is not a panacea.

Comment: @AdamO Can you explain what kind of? IMO an ATE could be calculated by weighting?

Comment: @gisela In the pharma world, we calculate ATE in intent-to-treat designs. "Balance covariates" has been kind of erroneously associated with well-controlled RCTs. Stephen Senn has written extensively on this point. In your case, either matching, adjustment, or weighting could be used to reduce confounding. But I seriously question the generalizability of results when a planned design using matching then employs weighting in the matched set.

Comment: @AdamO Thanks for the reply. Absolutely. My question was more of general interest and not associated with any current project. Just playing with fun data and trying to find my way into this subject..

Comment: @AdamO The size of the created pseudopopulation via weighting is inflated or deflated compared to original study population and further these weights are estimated based on PS and not truly known, a sandwich estimator is recommended. doi:10.1002/ sim.6607

Comment: RCTs are designed to answer conditional questions, and unconditional estimates like ATE do not transport from the clinical trial sample to the population.  ATE is an estimate that may not equal that of any patient in or out of the study, because covariate distributions differ between sample and population.

Comment: @FrankHarrell Exact, but the question is if it would be feasible to treat all eligible patients included in the study with treatment. Thus, results are not extrapolated and the target estimand corresponds to the ATE..

Comment: That does not align with individual patient decision making.  You are thinking of group decision making, e.g., do we close a school during a pandemic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Therneau and Grambsch](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387987842) describe some circumstances that might benefit from or even require robust sandwich-type variance estimates/standard errors in Cox survival models, specified by a `cluster(id)` term in R.

First, when there are highly influential individual observations (typically evaluated by "dfbeta" residuals, close to the "jackknife" differences in coefficient estimates seen after removing each observation individually), then the assumptions underlying the asymptotic multivariate normality of the usual coefficient covariance matrix might be questionable. If $D$ is the matrix of "dfbeta" residuals, then the robust coefficient covariance matrix is $D'D$. See Chapter 6 of Therneau and Grambsch.

The robust variance estimate *might* improve such a situation, but in small data sets there can be an "occasional outlying robust estimator" that might lead to worse performance. Therneau and Grambsch nevertheless "recommend examination of the sandwich estimate in cases where the Cox model assumptions are suspect." (p. 161)

A second situation is case weighting to correct for sampling. Robust standard errors are the default in R in that situation, as you note. Therneau and Grambsch illustrate that for a propensity score correction, in the context of missing data, in Section 7.3.

As the comments from Prof. Harrell indicate, (inverse) propensity score weighting might not be the best approach for dealing with propensities of receiving treatments in your application. I'd recommend at least searching for and reading both his and [@Noah's](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/116195/noah) answers to questions on this site about the strengths and weaknesses of matching and propensity scores. This is a difficult issue; you probably should consult a local statistical expert if you want to take this approach.

A third situation is when there can be multiple events per individual. That's discussed in Chapter 8 of Therneau and Grambsch. Robust standard errors are one way to take intra-individual correlations into account. Frailty models (discussed in Chapter 9) and [mixed-effect Cox models](https://cran.r-project.org/package=coxme) are other ways to deal with intra-individual correlations.

Robust variance estimates can also be used to deal with other types of correlations, like those among members of a family or among patients within hospitals or other institutions. The the `id` in `cluster(id)` would represent the family or institution. Frailty/mixed-model approaches are alternatives in this situation. Stratification by institution can adjust for differences in baseline hazards among institutions.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed reply. I recently read a paper using `Fine stratification weights (ATT)` stating they used robust SE to account for weighting - that sounded like general use in weighting.